# How to format / concatenate data in a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: pandas

What I'm trying to do would look like this in R:

```
df$C <- sprintf("%02d-%02d", df$A, df$B)
```

How is it done in Pandas? Here's the data frame with columns A and B, and the column C that I would like to generate by formatting and concatenate the numbers in A and B:

```
pandas.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [4,5,6],
                  "C": ["01-04", "02-05", "03-06"]})

   A  B      C
0  1  4  01-04
1  2  5  02-05
2  3  6  03-06
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `pandas`

```
df.apply(lambda x :  "%02d-%02d" % (x['A'],x['B']),axis=1)
Out[218]: 
0    01-04
1    02-05
2    03-06
dtype: object
```

Comment: Damn, I knew it had to be simple.

Answer (score 0):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd                                                                                                                                                                                 

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [4,5,6]})

In [9]: df['C']= df.apply(lambda x:"{:02d}-{:02d}".format(x['A'],x['B']), axis=1)                                                                                                                           

In [10]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                 
Out[12]: 
A  B      C
0  1  4  01-04
1  2  5  02-05
2  3  6  03-06
```